# Autodesk Data Management API create item in folder

Tags: autodesk-data-management

According to the Autodesk Forge references, a folder is ["a logical organization of items within a project"](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/overview/basics/). So that means that a folder contains several items.

But the webservice to create an item looks like that:

```
POST /data/v1/projects/{project_id}/items
```

This web-request only takes the project-id into account. But there seems to be no way, to provide the folder-id. So how can I create an item in a specific folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [creating an item](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-POST/), you need to pass (among other things) the parent folder id:

```
  // ......
  relationships: {
    // .....
    parent: {
      data: {
        type: "folders",
        id: FOLDER_ID_HERE
      }
    }
  }
  // ......
```

Comment: Oh. Thanks Augusto (again)